# auto scroll on loading view

Tags: html, angularjs, uiscrollview, angular-ui

so that's the problem,
when i walk through the application's view, the browser always set the scroll on the center of the page's y-axes. I have try solutions like this

```
var goToTop=function(){
    $location.hash('menu');
    $anchorScroll();
}
goToTop();
```

but the problem is that, first it didn't works always correct and second every time that the page is refreshing or loading, the scroll auto sets on the center and, after the loading, it goes to the div id='menu'.
I need somtehing else, like a scrollfix on the top, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adopted this solution:

## HTML

```
<div  class="main">
    <div ui-view autoscroll="header"></div>
</div>
```

following the documentation that i have found inside the file viewDirective.js, in the ui.router module.
It seems correct to say that substantially the ui-router view directive, automatically try to auto scroll on the view of the page, with this markup in html file you deactivate this function.